# prepend a line of text to a set of files using emacs

Tags: emacs

Is there any way of prepending a line of text to a set of files within emacs?

I can do search and replace across files using `find-grep-dired`, then marking the files and doing a target string - replacement string

But in this instance I don't want to 'replace' anything just prepend a single line to the start of a set of files with the '.ini' extension.

Comment: `find-name-dired` might be more appropriate for listing the `.ini` files? Unless you only wanted certain ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In emacs regular expressions, `` \` `` matches the beginning of the buffer.  So if you have all the files marked in a dired buffer, just do a `dired-do-query-replace-regexp` (<kbd>Q</kbd>) and replace `` \` `` with the line you'd like to prepend.